# Formula Field with line break in visualforce

Tags: visualforce, formula

I have a formula field that determines our company address based on a region (custom field) on account:

```
IF(CONTAINS(TEXT(Account__r.Region__c),"US"),
"Company, Inc." & BR() &"A street" & BR() & "Suite 530" & BR() &"Boston, MA 02210",
IF(NOT(ISPICKVAL(Account__r.Region__c,"")),"Company, Ltd." & BR() & "B Street" & BR() & "5th Floor" & BR() & " UK", "Please update account region"))
```

When using this field in a standard layout, it appear ok. i.e.:

> Company, Inc.
>  A street
>  Suite 530
>  Boston, MA 02210

I tried placing this field in a visualforce page using this format:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!Custom_Object__c.Company_Address__c}" escape="false"/>
```

and got this result:

> Company, Inc.
>  27-43
>  A Street
>  Suite 530
>  Boston,
>   MA
>  02210

Any explination why the line break happens and how I can fix it?

```
<apex:page standardController="Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c" showHeader="false" renderas="pdf"> 

<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" id="table1">
<tr>
    <td align="left">       <img src='{!URLFOR($Resource.Logo)}' title="logo" />
     <br/>
     <img src='{!URLFOR($Resource.InvoiceLogo)}' title="logo" />
       </td>

       <td align="right" > <apex:outputText value="{!Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Company_Address__c}" escape="false"/>    
    </td>
</tr>



</table>

<br/>

<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" id="table1">
<tr>    <td>


        Invoice Date: {!Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Invoice_Created_Date__c} <br/>
        Invoice #: {!Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Invoice_Number__c}<br/> 
        Billing Period: {!Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Billing_Period__c}  <br/> 
        Customer ID: {!Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Account__r.Customer_ID__c} <br/>


        </td> 
        <td width="50%"></td>

</tr>
</table>

<p><b><font face="Arial" color="#000080">Customer Information</font></b></p>

<table border="0" width="100%" id="table2">
<tr>
       <td colspan="3">
           <font face="Arial">{!Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Account__r.Name} <br/></font>
       </td>
</tr>
<tr>
       <td>          
           <font face="Arial">Attn: {!Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Contact__r.Name}<br/>

                             {!Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Account__r.BillingStreet}<br/>
                             {!Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Account__r.BillingCity}, {!Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Account__r.BillingState} {!Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Account__r.BillingPostalCode} <br/>
                             {!Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Account__r.BillingCountry} <br/>
                             Tel: {!Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Contact__r.Name}
           </font>
        </td>

</tr>    
</table>

<p><b><font color="#000080" face="Arial">Order Description</font></b></p>
<table border="1" width="100%" id="table4">
<tr>
       <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><font face="Arial">Product</font></td>
       <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0" align="center"><font face="Arial">Price Per VM</font></td>
       <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0" align="center"><font face="Arial">Average # of VM's</font></td>       
       <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0" align="center"><font face="Arial">Amount</font></td> 
</tr>
<tr>

             <td>Product</td>
             <td align="center"> {!Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Effective_Price_Per_VM_Per_Month__c}</td>  
             <td align="center">{!Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Reported_Usage__c}</td>             
             <td align="center">{!Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Reported_Usage_Price_Per_Vm__c} </td>  
          </tr>

<tr style="display: {!IF(ISBLANK(Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Adjustments__c), 'none', 'table-row')};">

    <td align="left"> Adjustments </td>  
    <td>  
    </td> 
      <td  align="center"> {!Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Adjustments__c}   </td> 
      <td> 
      </td>

</tr>

<tr style="display: {!IF(ISBLANK(Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Adjustments__c), 'none', 'table-row')};">

    <td align="left"> Reported Trial Usage </td>  
  <td>
    </td> 
  <td  align="center"> {!Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Reported_Trial_Usage__c}   </td>
   <td>
    </td>

</tr>

<tr style="display: {!IF(ISBLANK(Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Adjustments__c), 'none', 'table-row')};">

    <td align="left"> Net Usage For Billing  </td>  
  <td align = "center">
  {!Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Effective_Price_Per_VM_Per_Month__c}
    </td> 
  <td  align="center"> {!Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Net_Usage_For_Billing__c}   </td>

   <td align="center">
   {!Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Billing_Amount__c}
    </td>

</tr>



<tr>
       <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0" align="right" colspan="6">
       <font face="Arial"><b>Total Due:</b><apex:OutputField value="{!Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Billing_Amount__c}"/></font></td>
</tr>
</table>

<p><b><font color="#000080" face="Arial">Payment Instructions</font></b></p>
<table border="0" width="100%" id="table3">
 <tr>
       <td><font face="Arial">

             1. Payment is due in full 30 days from the INVOICE DATE <br/>

            </font>
        </td>

   <br/>

</tr> 



<table border="0" width="100%" id="table4">
<!--<tr>
       <td colspan="3">

       </td>
</tr> -->
<tr>
       <td>          
           <font face="Arial"><b>Wire transfer instructions:</b><br/>

                           <apex:OutputField value="{!Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Wire_transfer_instructions__c}"/>
           </font>
        </td>
    <!--    <td width="1%"></td> -->

        <td>
           <font face="Arial"><b>Check payment instructions:</b><br/>
                            <apex:OutputField value="{!Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Check_payment_instructions__c}"/>
           </font>
        </td>



</tr>    
</table>

</table>

<hr/>
<p align="center"><font face="Arial">If you have any question about this invoice, please contact. <br/>
{!Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Account__r.Owner.FirstName} {!Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Account__r.Owner.LastName}, {!Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Account__r.Owner.Phone}, {!Monthly_Cloud_Bill__c.Account__r.Owner.Email} <br/> <br/>
<b>Thank You For Your Business!</b>
</font></p>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Its likely to be word wrapping imposed by the browser by the container HTML element you have it in. Try playing with the width of the containing element and positioning of your outputText element on the page?

Answer (score 1):

You don't show us the format of the VF page you're putting this into, but I strongly suspect you're outputting this text into a table of some sort that isn't wide enough to allow everything to stay together. If you post the code for the page, we're much more likely to be able to provide more specific help. In general, my guess off-hand would be that you need to specify the min cell width in pixels for the column that you're displaying the company address in.

Your other option, would be to get each line of the company's address and output them one by one with a `<br></br>` between each of them. As in you'd need to get the company street address, followed by the City, then the State, zip, etc. Where possible, you'd also want to include a `&nbsp` between 27-43 (the street number) and the "A" along with "Street" as shown below if you want them all to stay together:

```
<p>27-43 &nbsp A &nbsp Street</p>
```

The above would keep all of the above on a single line. Any overflow would either be clipped or else flow into an adjacent column if the column was empty.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `<apex:outputField>` instead of `<apex:outputText>`, there is definitely some 'smart' formatting that occurs with the address fields in the system, using the former might yield a result consistent with the standard pages.